# How can I access another drive in my computer using PHP

Tags: php, xampp

My xampp was installed in c:/xampp.when my c:/ drive filled So I would like to access E:/ drive using PHP anybody give me some suggestions?

Comment: You modify the apache `httpd.conf` file

Comment: What did you try and which error messages did you get?

Comment: Please tell me httpd.conf setups for that @scuzzy

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store the current path, before changing dirs:

```
echo chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

$oldPath = getcwd();
chdir('/your_new_path');
include(./your_file.php);
chdir($oldPath);
```

Comment: But there is a little error simple it'll access another drive folder file out put is fine but it echoout 1 at last line of output